# При оформлении прямой речи, могут ли слова автора внутри неё быть разбиты на два и более предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Можно ли писать в диалоге нечто вроде:

— Готовы? — спросил учитель. Выражение его лица было сурово. — Тогда начинаем.

Или же второе предложение прямой речи тут следует начинать с нового абзаца, как-то так:

— Готовы? — спросил учитель. Выражение его лица было сурово.

— Тогда начинаем.

Стилистически, думаю, лучше написать "сурово спросил учитель", но меня интересует сам принцип.

Answer (score 4):

• В диалоге **можно** так написать (конечно же, без тире после "спросил учитель"):

*— Готовы? — **спросил учитель. Выражение его лица было сурово.** — Тогда начинаем.*

•• Имеются и похожие примеры, в которых во втором предложении описывается только **мимика** говорящего, а не конкретные его действия. Поэтому разделение слов автора на абзацы не требуется.

*— Так для чего же ты оставался? — спросила она, вдруг подняв на него глаза. **Выражение ее лица** было холодное и неприязненное. — Ты сказал Стиве, что останешься, чтоб увезти Яшвина. А ты оставил же его* (Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина).

*— Сделаем так, — начал он игру, устраиваясь удобнее на стуле; **выражение его лица** было довольное и хитрое. — Здесь курить, конечно, нельзя? — спросил он Настю* (В. Шукшин. Калина красная).
[Думаю, что здесь вместо точки с запятой можно поставить точку.]

*— Нормально, — пожал Фридман плечами. И тут же **выражение его лица** изменилось, оно стало вдруг очень напряженным. — А почему я должен был как-то плохо добраться? — вдруг колюче спросил он* (В. Гурвич. Воспитание элиты).

*— Дагон — рыба! Божество, но всего лишь рыба. Дагон прислушивается к словам Верховного жреца храма Воды, — сказал он, ухмыляясь. А потом **лицо его исказилось** и он заорал: — А морские чудовища слушаются Дагона!* (И. Суббота. Эксперт смерти).

Answer (score 2):

*— Готовы? — спросил учитель.  **Выражение его лица было сурово**. — Тогда начинаем.*

**Пояснение**

Оформление вызывает вопросы: соединение атрибуции и авторской речи при описании мимики. Перенести дословное высказывание на новый абзац **нельзя**, а то получится диалог с самим собой.

**Вот вариант:**

— Формула эта может иметь и другой вид, — **пояснил профессор.**

Он неторопливо подошел к доске, взял мел и написал что-то новое для нас.

— Вот это и есть другой вариант, — **сказал он.**

**Другой пример:**

– Да, это заметно. – **Павел Петрович начал, не торопясь, намазывать масло на хлеб.** – Долго он у нас прогостит?

**В качестве варианта:**

— Готовы? — **спросил учитель**. — Тогда начинаем.

Выражение его лица было сурово.

Comment: Мне кажется, что тире между  "спросил учитель" и "Выражение его лица..." выглядит странно, ведь и та, и другая фраза — слова автора.

Comment: Возможно, вы правы, выглядит странно. Тогда нужно другое оформление.  Дело в том, что у нас встречается атрибуция (спросил учитель) и слова автора (выражение его лица...). У этих предложений разный статус.  Надо поискать в текстах аналоги.

Comment: Да, в вашем примере про профессора второе предложение слов автора переносится на красную строку (в примере про Павла Петровича предложение одно, хотя и распространённое), что подразумевает, что объединять аттрибуцию и слова автора в новом предложении в одном абзаце по крайней мере, нежелательно. Но мне и в самом деле интересно, есть ли в классических или современных опубликованных текстах такие объединения.

Comment: Мне тоже интересно)  Надо это дело проверить.

Comment: Хотя вот и официальный источник: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161

4. Если между двумя репликами одного и того же говорящего лица находится текст от автора, то ни этот текст, ни последующая прямая речь в отдельные абзацы обычно не выделяются:

— Не получается что-то у меня с проводом, — ответил мастер. Он немного подумал и добавил: — Придётся всё делать заново.

Но если в тексте от автора описывается действие говорящего лица, то и авторский текст, и последующая прямая речь выделяются в абзацы.

Comment: То есть, допустимость конструкции — П, — а. А. — П. зависит от того, действует ли лицо в авторской речи активно, или нет. Тонко.

Answer (score 0):

У меня по теме  **«Абзацы при прямой речи»** ясности нет, а **вопросов много.**  Практические тексты дают материал, но нужны правила. Прежде всего, это классические правила Розенталя, но они не охватывают всю практику. Есть ли новые **исследования и рекомендации** по теме и где их найти?

**Вопросы такие.**

1. **Атрибуция:**  строчная буква;  слова, вводящие прямую речь. **Слова автора:** прописная буква; описание мимики и действий персонажа.

Можно ли их **соединять, где об этом сказано**?  Действия по Розенталю  выносятся в отдельный абзац, а **мимика?**

2. **Два атрибутивные глагола**

У **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161#pp161)** они **в одном предложении**:

```
  «Я тебя не спрашиваю, — строго сказал офицер и снова 
  спросил: — Старуха, отвечай?» (М. Г.);  «Покорно 
  благодарю, — отозвался Мешков, смиренно снял картузик, но 
  сразу опять надел и поклонился, добавив торопливо: — 
   Спасибо вам большое, товарищи» (Фед.).
```

**Можно ли их оформлять отдельно:**

— Так для чего же ты оставался? — **спросила она, вдруг подняв на него глаза. Выражение ее лица было холодное и неприязненное.** — Ты сказал Стиве, что останешься, чтоб увезти Яшвина. А ты оставил же его (Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина).

Можно ли поставить **точку с запятой**: — Так для чего же ты оставался? — спросила она, вдруг подняв на него глаза; выражение ее лица было холодное и неприязненное. — Ты сказал Стиве…

**Или так:** — Так для чего же ты оставался? — Она  спросила это, вдруг подняв на него глаза. Выражение ее лица было холодное и неприязненное. — Ты сказал Стиве …

**Аналогично**: — Дагон — рыба! Божество, но всего лишь рыба. Дагон прислушивается к словам Верховного жреца храма Воды, — сказал он, ухмыляясь; но  потом лицо его исказилось и он заорал: — А морские чудовища слушаются Дагона!

Я **не правлю Толстого**, просто хотелось бы видеть оформленный **по правилам** Розенталя текст. Или подтвердить такое оформление в других авторитетных источниках.

**Вывод.**  Соединение атрибуции (строчная буква) и слов автора (прописная буква) выглядит **странно**.  Хотелось бы это увидеть в правилах. А давать **собственные рекомендации** как-то не хочется. Наше дело — **применять правила**, а не формулировать их.

3. **Не рекомендуется такая атрибуция:**

— Сделаем так, — начал он игру…

— Нормально, — пожал Фридман плечами…

Все глаголы, которые авторы используют в диалогах, можно разделить **на однозначно атрибутивные, условно-атрибутивные, сомнительно-атрибутивные и вовсе не атрибутивные.**  https://blog.selfpub.ru/atributciya

Кстати, **у Шукшина** сценарий по его двум рассказам, а там, вероятно, другие правила.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу для сравнения **пример разного оформления** одного  текста:

**Оригинал:**

*— Нормально, — пожал Фридман плечами. И тут же выражение его лица изменилось, оно стало **вдруг** очень напряженным. — А почему я должен был как-то плохо добраться? — **вдруг** колюче спросил он.*

**Недостатки.**

(1) Атрибуция и слова автора в одой фразе. Насколько это **нормативно?**

(2) **[Атрибуция](https://blog.selfpub.ru/atributciya)** (приписывание, ввод прямой речи) оформлена **неверно.**

```
   С глаголами вовсе не атрибутивными, казалось бы, все 
   понятно — они не поясняют, кто или как произносит 
   реплику, а лишь сопутствуют действиям. Однако довольно 
   часто приходится читать что-нибудь вроде:
   — Вот и я так подумал, — затянулся сигаретой Олег.
   — Беги поиграй, — дал ей мячик дед.
   — Ты проиграл! — бросился за дверь он.
```

Все три примера содержат ошибку. Постарайтесь не использовать в качестве атрибуции сопутствующие реплике действия, оформляйте их отдельными предложениями:

```
    — Вот и я так подумал. — Олег затянулся сигаретой.
    — Беги поиграй. — Дед дал ей мячик.
    — Ты проиграл! — Он бросился за дверь.
```

**Редактирование**

*— Нормально.  — **Фридман пожал плечами**. И тут же выражение его лица изменилось, оно стало **вдруг** очень напряженным.*

*— А почему я должен был как-то плохо добраться? —  **колюче спросил он.***

Comment: Пишите, пожалуйста, ваши комментарии. Какой вариант вы считаете правильным и почему?  Есть ли у вас ссылка на правильность оригинала? Мне кажется, что смешение двух фраз  в одном абзаце  не выглядит оправданным,  в том числе по семантике. Ведь риторика персонажа резко меняется.  Также в оригинале повтор наречия "вдруг".

Comment: "Пожал плечами" относится скорее к мимике и жестам, а это, согласно вашей ссылке - "сомнительно-атрибутивный" глагол. Но непонятно, почему "пожал Фридман плечами", а не "пожал плечами Фридман"? Конструкция сказуемое-подлежащее-дополнение тут выглядит странно.

Согласен, что повтор "вдруг" кажется тавтологией, а не стилистическим приёмом.

Comment: Ладно, если "сомнительно-атрибутивный", то пусть будет.  А инверсия допустима (актуальное членение предложения). В этом случае ударением выделено последнее слово "плечами",  то есть жест подчеркнут.